# how to draw on any window from a widget in python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, drawing, jcolorchooser

I am new in python and i want to create a script in python which can let me draw or paint in my desktop or on any window like web browser etc.....

Can anybody tell me which library in python can i use to achieve something this.

As i want to draw directly on the desktop screen and not in any canvas or particular (seperate window for drawing)

From tkinter.colorchooser or something else.

The example image is shown below that's how i want. 
[image: eg]

how can i get a widget like this with only color option and default pen to draw. 
[image: jj]

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python in-built library Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor


class Paint(object):

    DEFAULT_PEN_SIZE = 5.0
    DEFAULT_COLOR = 'black'

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.pen_button = Button(self.root, text='pen', command=self.use_pen)
        self.pen_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.brush_button = Button(self.root, text='brush', command=self.use_brush)
        self.brush_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.color_button = Button(self.root, text='color', command=self.choose_color)
        self.color_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.eraser_button = Button(self.root, text='eraser', command=self.use_eraser)
        self.eraser_button.grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.choose_size_button = Scale(self.root, from_=1, to=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.choose_size_button.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.c = Canvas(self.root, bg='white', width=600, height=600)
        self.c.grid(row=1, columnspan=5)

        self.setup()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def setup(self):
        self.old_x = None
        self.old_y = None
        self.line_width = self.choose_size_button.get()
        self.color = self.DEFAULT_COLOR
        self.eraser_on = False
        self.active_button = self.pen_button
        self.c.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.paint)
        self.c.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.reset)

    def use_pen(self):
        self.activate_button(self.pen_button)

    def use_brush(self):
        self.activate_button(self.brush_button)

    def choose_color(self):
        self.eraser_on = False
        self.color = askcolor(color=self.color)[1]

    def use_eraser(self):
        self.activate_button(self.eraser_button, eraser_mode=True)

    def activate_button(self, some_button, eraser_mode=False):
        self.active_button.config(relief=RAISED)
        some_button.config(relief=SUNKEN)
        self.active_button = some_button
        self.eraser_on = eraser_mode

    def paint(self, event):
        self.line_width = self.choose_size_button.get()
        paint_color = 'white' if self.eraser_on else self.color
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.c.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                               width=self.line_width, fill=paint_color,
                               capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=36)
        self.old_x = event.x
        self.old_y = event.y

    def reset(self, event):
        self.old_x, self.old_y = None, None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Paint()
```

Comment: this is good and working. But i don't want to draw it in a window(tkinter) i want to draw on any desktop window or browser etc.

Comment: That is you want Python to take a fullscreen-screenshot and you want to draw on it. Right?

Comment: no i don't want to take screen shot i want to paint live on desktop. like you do while recording screen in some screen recording softwares. as a tutorial.

Comment: You can't use tkinter to draw on any window except the windows created by tkinter. This answer doesn't do what the question is asking for.

Comment: @InfinityTM i can make the window transparent and full screen to achieve what i want but i don't want that pen,eraser etc buttons i want a direct colour selection box with default pen to draw on it (image updated)